# Riemann zeta function at $\Re(s)=0$ and $\Re(s)=1$

Tags: riemann-zeta

Riemann zeta function at $\Re(s)=0$ and $\Re(s)=1$.

What happens to the zeta function at these points? For example $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^s}$ is defined for $\Re(s)>1$ and for $\Re(s)>0$ you have a different formula. But none of these include 0 or 1? Or does $\Re(S)>0$ include the 1? (or maybe it was defined wrong and should be $\Re(s)>0$ excluding $s=1$ in the book)

Comment: This is like asking "what happens to the function $\sum_{n\geq 0} z^n$ along $|z| = 1$?" The explicit series formula makes no sense there, but the function can be extended analytically from $|z| < 1$ to $\mathbf C -\{1\}$ by rewriting it as $1/(1-z)$. Something similar, but more subtle, can be done for $\zeta(s)$ on $\mathbf C - \{1\}$.

Comment: So is it  $\Re(s)>0 - \{1\}$ or $\Re(s)>0 -\{\Re(s)=1\}$?

Comment: You don't tell us what book, or what formula, so it's hard to answer your question, but a formula for real part greater than zero should work for real part equal to one (except of course at $s=1$, where there is a pole).

Answer (score 2):

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\zeta\big(1^\pm\big)=\pm\infty~$ and $~\zeta(0)=-\dfrac12$

---

[image]

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ The plot of $\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s)=0.$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ The real part is in blue, and the imaginary part is in red.

---

[image]

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ The plot of $\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s)=1.$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ The real part is in blue, and the imaginary part is in red.

---

[image]

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ The plot of $\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s)=\dfrac12$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ The real part is in blue, and the imaginary part is in red.

---

[image: 1]

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ The plot of $\zeta(x)$ for $x\in(-14,-1).$

---

[image]

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ The plot of $\zeta(x)$ for $x\in(-20,~1).$

$\quad$ Notice how each new “hump” to the left gets exponentially bigger than the previous one.

Comment: We also have $~\lim\limits_{x\to0^\pm}\zeta(1+x)-\dfrac1x=\gamma,~$ see [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant) for more information.

Comment: See also the [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation) and the [particular values at negative integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Negative_integers) of the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Answer (score 0):

The zeta function, written in the series form you wrote down above, is only defined for the $Re(s)>1$, but it has an "analytic continuation" that is defined everywhere on the complex plane (not just $Re(s)>0$) except at $s=1$ where it has a simple pole. Thus it will have a well defined value at $=0$, which is $\zeta(0)= -1/2$.

For more information I recommend the book by H.M. Edwards, "Riemann's Zeta Function". It might also be useful to look up the notion of analytic continuation in any complex analysis textbook.